# Translate "Crater Lake" into classical Latin

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

From what I have read of [this post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/noun-adjuncts-in-latin), Latin doesn't really use nouns as adjectives in the way that English does, although that post mentions you can use a noun in genitive case to achieve this. I am translating "Crater Lake" as the name of a location, and came up with the following based on that advice: *Lacus Crateris*.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds perfectly fine to me. You are correct about the genitive. An alternative could be *Lacus Craterae*; for both *crater* and *cratera* exist, with the same meaning, which includes the drinking-vessel and a volcanic crater.

It is conceivable that the Romans might have used an adjective, like *?craterius* or similar, but I have not found actual use of this.

P.S. A famous crater lake is *[Lacus Avernus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Avernus)*, where the entrance to my world is said to lie.

Comment: Lacus Curtius...

Answer (score 3):

On the other hand, it is perfectly classical Latin to use a proper noun and a common noun in apposition as in “urbs Roma”. If you want to take “Crater” as the English name of the lake you can write “lacus Crater”.